# How to use ui-select group-filter property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

Hey Guys I want to use ui-select. But I got stock on the group-filter property:

I got an Array from my server containing groups:

Group looks like this:

```
{"1":{"id":"1","name":"DLRG G&ouml;ttingen e.V.","idCategory":"1","categoryName":"Verein"}}
```

So there are some categories more like family, company and so on.

I have to ui-select fields, one for families and an other for all other categories.

I tried filtering by using this method:

```
filterFamily() {
      var families = {};
// this.groupList contains all groups
      for (var i; i < this.groupList; i++) {
        if (this.groupList[i].idKategorie == 2) {
          families.push(this.groupList[i]);
        }
      }
      return families;
    }
```

In my html I try to use the filter with:

```
   <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.group">
                  <ui-select-match>
                    <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
                  </ui-select-match>
                  <ui-select-choices group-filter="ctrl.filterFamily()" repeat="item in ctrl.groupList | propsFilter:{name: $select.search}">
                    <div ng-if="item.isTag"
                         ng-bind-html="item.name +' <small>(new)</small>'| highlight: $select.search"></div>
                    <div ng-if="!item.isTag" ng-bind-html="item.name + person.isTag| highlight: $select.search"></div>
                    <small>
                      {{item.kategorieName}}
                    </small>
                  </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
```

But in this field all other items are shown too?

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be `group-filter="ctrl.filterFamily"`, not `group-filter="ctrl.filterFamily()"`, although I have never used this project before.

That is how it's used in the [docs though](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/f5260eaa2e9ded276943ba45e39d1cc9c670ed86/examples/demo-groupfilter.html)

Comment: This doesn't take the wanted effect. My solution is a work around. I made a second array and iterate over this in my view.